# Most reliable way to detect if a visitor comes from Google Search?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How would you determine how a visitors is coming from Google, other search engine or any other channel? I want to show a one-off coupon code to my Google Search visitors.

Not sure how to do it though - I run my website on PHP/WORDPRESS/JQUERY.

Answer (score 1):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will
>   set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a
>   feature. **In short, it cannot really be trusted.**

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Is that what google analytics uses for example? If so then I guess it is decent enough (nothing critical to be used against it so should be fine in most cases)

Comment: @Lazhar what google analytics uses is trade secret. so no one knows for sure. But as HTTP is stateless there is a limited number of options. so more than likely yes, this is the same approach.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP_REFERER includes google.com so you know it came from a google search, but not what was searched for.

Answer (score 0):

From the front side (javascript) you can get it from `document.referrer`